# What is this error about perllocale in Perldoc?

Tags: macos, perl, debugging, documentation, locale

I was discussing [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/209776/16920) about setting no locales in Perl and was recommended to run this `perldoc perllocale` in OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 but I get the error:

```
Error while formatting with Pod::Perldoc::ToMan:

 at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/Pod/Perldoc.pm line 1346.


 at /usr/bin/perldoc5.18 line 11.
Got a 0-length file from /System/Library/Perl/5.18/pods/perllocale.pod via Pod::Perldoc::ToMan!?

 at /usr/bin/perldoc5.18 line 11.
```

`which perldoc` gives `/usr/bin/perldoc` so correct should be. 
`echo $PATH` gives

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/texbin:/Users/masi/.cabal/bin
```

where I notice to have some folders two times there but the possible overwriting should not be the cause of the problem. 
My `.bashrc` is empty but `.profile` has just `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

What does this Perldoc error mean?

Comment: @toolic Can you, please, give any method to check and verify this as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the exact same error on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

```
bessarabov@bessarabov-osx:~$ perldoc perllocale
Error while formatting with Pod::Perldoc::ToMan:

 at /System/Library/Perl/5.18/Pod/Perldoc.pm line 1346.


 at /usr/bin/perldoc5.18 line 11.
Got a 0-length file from /System/Library/Perl/5.18/pods/perllocale.pod via Pod::Perldoc::ToMan!?

 at /usr/bin/perldoc5.18 line 11.
bessarabov@bessarabov-osx:~$
```

The command `perldoc -l perllocale` shows the path the the file:

```
bessarabov@bessarabov-osx:~$ perldoc -l perllocale
/System/Library/Perl/5.18/pods/perllocale.pod
bessarabov@bessarabov-osx:~$
```

The file is not empty and I've saved it to https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/20370992150a332dc0f0

OSX Yosemite 10.10.3 has perldoc version 3.19:

```
bessarabov@bessarabov-osx:~$ perl -MPod::Perldoc -E 'say $Pod::Perldoc::VERSION'
3.19
bessarabov@bessarabov-osx:~$
```

You can run `PERLDOCDEBUG=5 perldoc perllocale` to see some debug info - here is the log https://gist.github.com/bessarabov/6e09b4e491d5a00c6304 but it is not very usefull.

I tried to find out why the perldoc fails. I don't have the exact answer, but the problem is with this part of code in the file `/System/Library/Perl/5.18/Pod/Perldoc/ToMan.pm`:

```
while( $offset <= $length ) {
    $self->debug( "Writing chunk $chunks\n" ); $chunks++;
    syswrite $writer, ${ $self->{_text_ref} }, $chunk_size, $offset
        or $self->die( $! );
    $offset += $chunk_size;
    ...
}
```

Several interations of this loop works, but then `syswrite` dies, and `$!` has no information about the error.

I was able to read the documentation with other parser:

```
perldoc -MPod::Perldoc::ToText perllocale
```

The other way to solve this issue is to update to the latest version of [Pod::Perldoc](https://metacpan.org/release/Pod-Perldoc) — perldoc 3.25 works fine with this file.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, I'd say the perllocale.pod file, which is supposed to have the perllocale documentation in pod format, is empty.

You can read the same documentation online at http://perldoc.perl.org/5.18.2/perllocale.html

Comment: Not very likely. Pod::Perldoc::ToMan through an exception, so it's no surprise it returned an empty file. The value of `$@` is really weird, though?!?!?